# How do I find the last occurrence in a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file which I have converted into a list. I am trying to call a function on the last occurrence of a 'value' in the list.

```
for n in l:
  if n[0] == 'value':
   new_value  = l[len('value')-1]
My_function(l)
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-ee7c16eb1946> in <cell line: 4>()
```

I want to call the function on the line specified in line 3

Comment: Why are you using `len('value')` in the index?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. The value of the last occurrence will be `"value"`. Do you mean you want to call the function on the whole row that contains it?

Comment: I think you just want `new_value = n` and then `My_function(new_value)`

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the list in reverse. Then you can break out of the loop when you find `value`.

```
last_row = None
for row in reversed(l):
    if row[0] == 'value':
        last_row = row
        break

if last_row:
    My_function(last_row)
```